# IOException during Directory.Move on Windows 7

Tags: c#, ioexception

I've inherited a C# app which has recently been deployed to Windows 7 workstations. Before this it has been running on many Windows XP workstations without experiencing the issue below.

The section of code in question tries to move a directory, using a loop in a thread. On the Windows 7 machines an *IOException* is caught. According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) *IOException* can be caused by 3 conditions. I am wondering if the loop may be trying to move the directory more than once, which might cause the "*destination already exists*" condition.

The symptom is that the warning MessageBox is shown repeatedly, but the move will eventually succeed. From my interpretation of the code, this should only happen after 60 seconds (300 * 200ms), but it seems to occur almost instantly.

As my experience with C# is very small, and my experience with threads even smaller, I'm at a loss here! I'm wondering if there is anything obviously wrong with the code in question.

The relevant section of code is below.

```
    public static string archiveBatch(Batch myBatch, string from)
    {
        string to = "";

        to = FileSystemManager.getArchivePath(myBatch, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(from));

        threadedMove tm = new threadedMove(from ,to);

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tm.run));
        t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        t.Start();

        return to;
    }

    private class threadedMove
    {
        string archivePath;
        string fromPath;

        public threadedMove(string from, string to)
        {
            archivePath = to;
            fromPath = from;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            int errorCounter = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                errorCounter++;
                if (TryToMove(fromPath, archivePath)) { break; }
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                if (errorCounter > 300)
                {
                    throw (new Exception("Warning: could not archive file from "+fromPath+" to "+archivePath));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool TryToMove(string source, string destination)
    {
        try
       {
             //check if path is file or folder
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(source))
            {
                //it is a file
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(destination))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(source, destination);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //it is a directory
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destination))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.Move(source, destination);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Warning: could not archive file from " + source + " to " + destination", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd rather not set the thread priority to highest.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and thought, "Hmmmmm.....". I wonder if it's been done to try and ensure that the thread completes its work before 300 iterations.

Comment: It's pretty rare for changing thread priorities in .Net to have any observable effect anyway, so I'd remove that line too.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start by outputting the exception message into the messagebox to see if it sheds some light on exactly why the exception is being thrown by doing this:

```
catch (IOException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Warning: could not archive file from " + source + " to " + destination + ". Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return false;
}
```

Once you know the reason you can then look at how to prevent it

Also what is `Batch`? It looks like it could be trying to move it to the same location, by that's just how it looks to me without knowing more about `Batch`

Comment: Thanks! The destination location is always different (according to the error in the MessageBox), so I don't think we're having a problem with the source and dest being the same.

Comment: +1, intentionally hiding the *exact* message you need to diagnose the problem is always a mistake.  Nobody can diagnose a 'it didn't work' message.